# IOS - didreceivenotification not called

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm trying to add push-notification to my app (unsuccessfully). I did the developer certificate for notification.
didregisterfornotification is called, then I upload the token to my server.

I Uploaded the .p12 on the server (before that I had an error on the server).
So, now, there is no error but the didreceivenotification or didlaunchwithoption are not called. 
I tried a lot of things but it's still not working.

Why I am not receiving notification ?

Comment: here is the good tutorial, http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1, hope it will help you

Comment: "I tried a lot of things" is of no use. State the things you did if you expect help.

Comment: Are you using the sandbox URL? Also as suhit said, use the raywenderlich.com tutorial.

Comment: the url was wrong on the server ..., problem solved, thank you!